# How to solve (synaptics) bug that causes X crashs?

Tags: centos, xorg, centos-7, toshiba-laptop, x-windows

I have a Toshiba laptop running CentOS 7, where X would crash from time to time (see below (from) output of `abrt-cli list -d`).

[Bug 877464](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=877464) may be relevant (but I already have `xorg-x11-drv-synaptics-1.9.0-2.el7.x86_64` installed).

**Any ideas on how to solve these X crashes?**

```
id afa24b4cbf4c47886d448aad72cf58aa25273523
reason:         Xorg server crashed
time:           Mon 29 Jun 2020 07:52:56 PM PDT
package:        xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.20.4-10.el7
uid:            0 (root)
count:          3225
Directory:      /var/spool/abrt/xorg-2020-06-29-19:52:56-10816-1
abrt_version:   2.1.11
analyzer:       xorg
architecture:   x86_64
component:      xorg-x11-server
duphash:        77e839b16e8026783d9cbccd77df9f6d2a1749ba
event_log:      
executable:     /usr/bin/X
hostname:       jeremy-laptop.local
kernel:         3.10.0-1127.13.1.el7.x86_64
last_occurrence: 1593549799
os_release:     CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)
pkg_arch:       x86_64
pkg_epoch:      0
pkg_fingerprint: 24C6 A8A7 F4A8 0EB5
pkg_name:       xorg-x11-server-Xorg
pkg_release:    10.el7
pkg_vendor:     CentOS
pkg_version:    1.20.4
runlevel:       N 5
type:           xorg
username:       root
uuid:           77e839b16e8026783d9cbccd77df9f6d2a1749ba

Xorg.0.log:     Text file, 110238 bytes
dmesg:          Text file, 155397 bytes
etc_X11_xorg_conf_d.tar.gz: Binary file, 332 bytes
usr_share_xorg_conf_d.tar.gz: Binary file, 2523 bytes

backtrace:
:0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x55) [0x55d8119783b5]
:1: /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so (0x7f869efd7000+0x4ed8) [0x7f869efdbed8]
:2: /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so (0x7f869efd7000+0x6bd2) [0x7f869efddbd2]
:3: /usr/bin/X (0x55d8117c7000+0x1b347c) [0x55d81197a47c]
:4: /usr/bin/X (0x55d8117c7000+0x1b5b52) [0x55d81197cb52]
:5: /usr/bin/X (0x55d8117c7000+0x1b32d6) [0x55d81197a2d6]
:6: /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x7f86a86a4000+0x7ea5) [0x7f86a86abea5]
:7: /lib64/libc.so.6 (clone+0x6d) [0x7f86a83d48dd]

dso_list:
:/usr/bin/X xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.20.4-10.el7.x86_64 (CentOS) 1593110822
:/usr/lib64/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so xorg-x11-drv-synaptics-1.9.0-2.el7.x86_64 (CentOS) 1593110822
:/lib64/libpthread.so.0 glibc-2.17-307.el7.1.x86_64 (CentOS) 1593110669
:/lib64/libc.so.6 glibc-2.17-307.el7.1.x86_64 (CentOS) 1593110669

machineid:
:systemd=eb2936f1c4c24b14be28f64b2805be95
:sosreport_uploader-dmidecode=c712c4fc17cb7552532c69948a32d0115633e628106c3ae07ea31f937e1c86f9

os_info:
:NAME="CentOS Linux"
:VERSION="7 (Core)"
:ID="centos"
:ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
:VERSION_ID="7"
:PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
:ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
:CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
:HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
:BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"
:
:CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
:CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
:REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
:REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
:
```

and

```
$ sudo cat  /var/spool/abrt/xorg-2020-06-29-19:52:56-10816-1/Xorg.0.log | tail -20
  Auth name: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ID: 442
[320407.987] AUDIT: Mon Jun 29 17:27:50 2020: 12089: client 25 connected from local host ( uid=1001 gid=1001 pid=2963 )
  Auth name: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ID: 442
[320407.987] AUDIT: Mon Jun 29 17:27:50 2020: 12089: client 25 disconnected
[320668.574] AUDIT: Mon Jun 29 17:32:11 2020: 12089: client 25 connected from local host ( uid=1001 gid=1001 pid=4233 )
  Auth name: MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 ID: 442
[320668.575] AUDIT: Mon Jun 29 17:32:11 2020: 12089: client 25 disconnected
[329112.802] (EE) BUG: triggered 'if (priv->num_active_touches > priv->num_slots)'
[329112.802] (EE) BUG: synaptics.c:2941 in UpdateTouchState()
[329112.802] (EE) 
[329112.802] (EE) Backtrace:
[329112.803] (EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x55) [0x55d8119783b5]
[329112.803] (EE) 1: /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so (0x7f869efd7000+0x4ed8) [0x7f869efdbed8]
[329112.803] (EE) 2: /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so (0x7f869efd7000+0x6bd2) [0x7f869efddbd2]
[329112.803] (EE) 3: /usr/bin/X (0x55d8117c7000+0x1b347c) [0x55d81197a47c]
[329112.803] (EE) 4: /usr/bin/X (0x55d8117c7000+0x1b5b52) [0x55d81197cb52]
[329112.803] (EE) 5: /usr/bin/X (0x55d8117c7000+0x1b32d6) [0x55d81197a2d6]
[329112.803] (EE) 6: /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x7f86a86a4000+0x7ea5) [0x7f86a86abea5]
[329112.803] (EE) 7: /lib64/libc.so.6 (clone+0x6d) [0x7f86a83d48dd]
[329112.803] (EE)
```